# How do I use Public Key Encryption with the AWS Encryption SDK in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm a bit out to sea on this one, so I was wondering whether anyone could help.

Does anyone know how to use Public Key encryption/decryption, using RSA keys in PEM format?

I can get it to work if I use the private key in both directions, I can get the public key to encrypt, but I don't know how to structure a script to get it to work if I want to use a public key to encrypt and a private key to decrypt. I see there is an example in the Java based version of the SDK, but I can't even figure it out from that.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Some sample code of the encryption process i'm using with a public key:

```
import os
import aws_encryption_sdk
from aws_encryption_sdk.internal.crypto import WrappingKey
from aws_encryption_sdk.key_providers.raw import RawMasterKeyProvider
from aws_encryption_sdk.identifiers import WrappingAlgorithm, EncryptionKeyType


class StaticPublicMasterKeyProvider(RawMasterKeyProvider):
    provider_id = 'static-public'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._public_keys = {}

    def _get_raw_key(self, key_id):
                
        with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
            public_key = key_file.read()
        self._public_keys[key_id] = public_key

        return WrappingKey(
            wrapping_algorithm=WrappingAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_SHA512_MGF1,
            wrapping_key=public_key,
            wrapping_key_type=EncryptionKeyType.PUBLIC
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    source_file = r'myfile.jpg'

    source_file_enc = source_file + '.encrypt'    
    
    public_key_id = os.urandom(8)
    master_key_provider = StaticPublicMasterKeyProvider()
    master_key_provider.add_master_key(public_key_id)

    with open(source_file, 'rb') as sf, open(source_file_enc, 'wb') as sfe:
        with aws_encryption_sdk.stream(
            mode='e',
            source=sf,
            key_provider=master_key_provider
        ) as encryptor:
            for chunk in encryptor:
                sfe.write(chunk)
```

I have reviewed the python examples on AWS and they are using private keys in both directions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: links to documentation:

[AWS Encryption SDK Developers Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html)

[Python example generating RSA Key but using private key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python-example-code.html#python-example-multiple-providers)

[Java example using RSA Public key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-example-code.html#java-example-multiple-providers)

Note:  the two examples use multiple key providers, but still incorporate RSA Keys

Comment: *I have reviewed the python examples on AWS and they are using private keys in both directions.* Very, very, unlikely, unless they are demonstrating both signing and encryption with RSA.  As I am not familiar with AWS perhaps you can include links to the documentation and examples.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk , I have updated the above with the appropriate links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have finally been given the example that I needed.  For current context, the current example resides in a feature branch only on github (so caution in the future, as this link may be broken.  You may need to search in master to find the example needed):

https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-python/blob/keyring/examples/src/master_key_provider/multi/aws_kms_with_escrow.py

The guts of it can be described as follows (directly out of the above example):

```
    # Create the encrypt master key that only has access to the public key.
    escrow_encrypt_master_key = RawMasterKey(
        # The provider ID and key ID are defined by you
        # and are used by the raw RSA master key
        # to determine whether it should attempt to decrypt
        # an encrypted data key.
        provider_id="some managed raw keys",  # provider ID corresponds to key namespace for keyrings
        key_id=b"my RSA wrapping key",  # key ID corresponds to key name for keyrings
        wrapping_key=WrappingKey(
            wrapping_key=public_key_pem,
            wrapping_key_type=EncryptionKeyType.PUBLIC,
            # The wrapping algorithm tells the raw RSA master key
            # how to use your wrapping key to encrypt data keys.
            #
            # We recommend using RSA_OAEP_SHA256_MGF1.
            # You should not use RSA_PKCS1 unless you require it for backwards compatibility.
            wrapping_algorithm=WrappingAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_SHA256_MGF1,
        ),
    )

    # Create the decrypt master key that has access to the private key.
    escrow_decrypt_master_key = RawMasterKey(
        # The key namespace and key name MUST match the encrypt master key.
        provider_id="some managed raw keys",  # provider ID corresponds to key namespace for keyrings
        key_id=b"my RSA wrapping key",  # key ID corresponds to key name for keyrings
        wrapping_key=WrappingKey(
            wrapping_key=private_key_pem,
            wrapping_key_type=EncryptionKeyType.PRIVATE,
            # The wrapping algorithm MUST match the encrypt master key.
            wrapping_algorithm=WrappingAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_SHA256_MGF1,
        ),
    )
```

If needs be, the `escrow_encrypt_master_key` can be added to a key ring to provide multiple keys to encrypt your payload.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks